# intersection of Spatial Poligons in r

Tags: r, geospatial

I have two different large spatial polygon data frames, one containing shapes of countries, and another with shapes of climate zones. I need to map climate zones into countries by "averaging" the prevalent climate zone in each country.
Can someone help with this issue?

I have tried intersections with `over()` function and `raster::union()`

Comment: can you `dput()` some sample data for both the objects `countries` and `shapes of climate zones` ?

Comment: I agree, it is difficult to provide an answer if we do not have an example that we can reproduce.